# Splash screen with fade in animation of ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, android-studio

So i am trying to implement splash screen with image view fade in animation which i want to start simultaneously with the start of the splash screen activity. I also want splash screen activity to end after short delay (on touch event is optional), after animation of image view is finished.

My SplashScreen.java:

```
package hillbillys.delivery;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements Animation.AnimationListener {
protected Animation fadeIn;
protected ImageView img1;
protected ImageView img2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen_splash);

    fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fade_in);

    /*
                img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img1.startAnimation(fadeIn);
                img2.startAnimation(fadeIn);
     */

    Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep (2000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {


}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Animation Stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
}
```

Application crashes every time i try to add the block of code in comment, no matter where i put it. Without fade in animation works everything just fine. Is there any way how to synchronize these two in easy way? Im quite new with coding so there may be some fatal mistake in what im trying to achieve.

My screeen_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff0d9"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/logo1"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/logo2"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true">

<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    />

</set>
```

Comment: You could use Picasso for the loading the ImageView and the fade animation. After sleep(2000) just use Picasso again.

Answer (score 3):

you need to initialize the `ImageView` before trying to access their properties. E.g.

```
img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
img1.startAnimation(fadeIn);
img2.startAnimation(fadeIn);
```

Comment: ok, you were faster with answer :D I would delete my to not spam

Answer (score 0):

Like Blackbelt said you need to initialize,

```
final img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
final img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
```

and if you want to the animation to start correctly after the view is created you need to do this

```
img1.post(new Runnable(){
    img1.startAnimation(fadeIn);
});

img2.post(new Runnable(){
    img2.startAnimation(fadeIn);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadeIn);
img1.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Thanks for participating. Coe-Only answers are discouraged. Please give some explanation for better understanding.